# PHP SimpleTest: How to get a value from webpage?

Tags: php, html, simpletest

I use [SimpleTest](http://www.simpletest.org/) for testing my pages written in PHP.

I have a form where you can enter several names at once. Then you click on "Generate Usernames and Passwords".

My test can set the names using setField('txtname', 'test user') and my test can click on the submit button. But how do I get the values of a generated username and password so that I can use this information to check if the login works?

The generated html code I want to retrieve the username and password from looks like this:

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
<thead>
<tr bgcolor="EEEEEE">
<th align=left>Last Name</th><th align=left>First Name</th><th align=left>Username</th>       
<th align=left>Password</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td>Test</td><td>User</td><td  id=username1>UserTest</td>
    <td id=password1>1a818</td></tr>
<tr>
    <td>Gates</td><td>Bill</td><td  id=username2>BillGates1</td>
    <td id=password2>aa37c</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Thanks for any tips.

Philip

Comment: Why do you use SimpleTest? It's old and unmaintained and the de-facto standard is PHPUnit. PHPUnit has support for Selenium, which is what you need to use when wanting to test WebUIs. PHPUnit also has assertions for comparing HTML content.

Comment: @Gordon: I didn't mention that I use the codeigniter Framework which apparently doesn't support PHPUnit very well. But some say testing codeigniter with PHPUnit can be done. If it isn't possible with SimpleTest then I'll give it a try.

Comment: @Gordon: I gave up with Codeigniter in combination with PHPUnit. Then I noticed you mentioning Selenium. I just downloaded the Firefox plugin for Selenium. This is all I need. Thanks again.

Comment: Cool. Do you want me to put that as an answer? Otherwise, you could just delete the question :)

Comment: @Gordon: Yeah, maybe it will help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Selenium to test user interfaces:

- http://seleniumhq.org/